# Как получить доступ к контейнеру с redis из другого контейнера?

Tags: docker, redis, dockerfile

Всем здравствуйте, как можно получить доступ к контейнеру с redis из другого контейнер?

Comment: запустить оба контейнера внутри одной сети

Answer (score 1):

Есть два пути.

1. Пробрасываете порт с хоста в контейнер с БД Redis, потом обращаетесь с любого другого контейнера по IP:PORT. Делается это либо через параметр -p , где можно и IP и PORT указать, или через указание EXPOSE в Dockerfile. Решение универсальное, позволяет получить доступ к данным с любого места, можно даже "снаружи" хоста. Но вообще это не лучшее решение, из соображений безопасности. Поэтому применить можно второй способ.
2. Выполнить так называемую линковку контейнеров.

То есть контейнеру с БД Redis дать название через --name myredis. А в тех контейнерах, где оно будет использоваться подключить его через --link myredis:redis. Соответственно внутри этих контейнеров можно будет использовать что-то вроде redis:6379, будет обращение в контейнер с именем myredis.

Обычно это работает сразу без проблем, но в некоторых случаях может понадобится создать отдельное сеть для свяжи между контейнерами, если у вас много разных приложений и вы хотите изолировать приложение с БД. Смысл остается тот же c именами, но при запуске обоих контейнеров указывается название сети и тогда контейнер с приложением будет видеть контейнер с Redis, а другие контейнеры вне этой сети - не будут.